# jQuery tipsy on datatables (live update)

Tags: jquery, datatables, tipsy

I have a table using the [datatable](http://datatables.net/) plugin with a link using the [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) plugin.

I have a link that uses tipsy and works fine with the following code:

```
<tr class="gradeX">
    <td class="valign"><a href="#" title="" class="btnIconLeft leftDir mr10" original-title="Test"><span style="width:90px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Test</span></a></td>
    <td class="valign center">1</td>
    <td class="center valign">1</td>
    <td class="center valign">29/05/2012</td>
    <td class="valign"></td>
</tr>
```

jS:

```
    $('.leftDir').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'e', live: true});
```

However as soon as I press page two on the table, none of the others work.

I think its either due to the live update or the fact that the next 10 rows are hidden, and the tooltip remains hidden

Comment: Are you sure the other pages are hidden? Can you see your tooltip if you inspect the HTML ?

Comment: Thats exactly what happened, Datatables uses the `.draw()` function (see below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to add this line:

```
$('.leftDir').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'e', live: true});
```

as an event. There is an event that is triggered when you press second page/filter or do anything that changes the table. Try this:

```
$(oTable).on("draw", function() {
    $('.leftDir').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'e', live: true});
});
```

Now the `tipsy` part will be added on every draw of the table. So if you switch pages it should be working fine.